# Writing data from MATLAB to firebase database

Tags: json, firebase, matlab, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I am using MATLAB to write data from MATLAB to firebase. I am using following lines of code to do so:

```
thingSpeakURL = 'https://hybrid-cabinet-265907.firebaseio.com/Ship A/Time Stamp.json';
lat = num2str(42);
lon = num2str(42);
data = struct('lat',lat,'lon',lon);
webwrite(thingSpeakURL,data)
```

Data is successfully written to Firebase. It is making my original JSON data as a child to a random string been generated on run-time.
For example, my JSON string is {lat: '40',lon:'40'} but instead it is creating a random string, let say, "Mxkkllslsll-1112", making that random string as parent and writing something like {"Mxkkllslsll-1112": lat:'40', lon:'40'} to the firebase database.

Please have a look at following image. It shows that for ship A, I have written data from MATLAB and it is not writing properly(I am facing the problem which I discussed above). I want to make it something like  data written for Ship B.
[image]

I want to write the data without making any random string as a parent. Kindly assist me in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `webwrite` uses the HTTP POST method by default.

As shown in the [Firebase Realtime Database REST API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-put), if you do a POST you will push the data and therefore automatically generate a unique key every time a new child is added to the specified Firebase reference (the `-MDJVMk.....` value we can see in your question).

You need to use the PUT method.

I don't know matlab but a rapid look at the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/weboptions.html) shows that you need to use the `RequestMethod` option with a `put` value, in the `weboptions` object.

Answer (score 0):

The above pushed me in the right direction (thanks!), and I had success with the following.

**CAUTION:** The following will overwrite everything in your database!

```
url = 'https://***.firebaseio.com/.json';

data.users(1) = struct('first','John','last','Locke'); 
data.users(2) = struct('first','Thomas','last','Hobbes'); 
data.users(3) = struct('first','Rene','last','Descartes');

headers = {'Content-Type' 'application/json'; 'Accept' 'application/json'}; 
options = weboptions('RequestMethod', 'put', 'HeaderFields', headers, 'ArrayFormat', 'json'); 
response = webwrite(url, data, options);
```

If your data is stored in a .json file (i.e., you don't want to create structures manually in Matlab), you can read it using "fileread" and pass in data as a string (instead of a structure).